# How to give weight to full matches over partial matches (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I've got a query that takes an input searches for the closet match in zipcode/region/city/metrocode in a location table containing a few tens of thousands of entries (should be nearly every city in the US). The query I'm using is:

```
select
  metrocode,
  region,
  postalcode,
  region_full,
  city
from
  dv_location
where
(
  region ilike '%Chicago%'
 or
  postalcode ilike '%Chicago%'
 or
  city ilike '%Chicago%'
 or
  region_full ilike'%Chicago%'
)

 and metrocode is not null
```

Odd thing is, the results set I'm getting back looks like this:

```
metrocode;region;postalcode;region_full;city
862;CA;95712;California;Chicago Park
862;CA;95712;California;Chicago Park
602;IL;60611;Illinois;Chicago
602;IL;60610;Illinois;Chicago
```

What am I doing wrong? My thinking is that Chicago would have greater weight than Chicago Park since Chicago is an exact match to the term (even though I'm asking for a wildcard match on the term).

Comment: Please format your output as code.

Comment: You're really getting duplicate rows returned with that exact query? Or are these unique rows that happen to have the exact same values for the 5 fields you are selecting?

Comment: The posted result makes perfect sense according to your query.  Can you add an example of what you are expecting to see?

Comment: Phrogz: No - the subset of columns just happen to be identical. kevpie: I'm expecting it to match "Chicago" before it matches "Chicago Park", but I might be misunderstanding how a string with % on either side would work. - mu is too short: In short, yes. I'm asking it for all results that are like '%Chicago%', and logically in my mind I would return results that match closest to that term, but my mind doesn't work the way PostgreSQL does. =)

Comment: @kagaku: The result set order is implementation defined (i.e. as good as random for all practical purposes) if you don't specify the order with an explicit `ORDER BY` clause. Relational databases and SQL are set based (in the mathematical sense) so there is no implicit ordering, ordering has to be explicitly specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
  metrocode,
  region,
  postalcode,
  region_full,
  city,
  (region = 'Chicago'
   OR postalcode = 'Chicago'
   OR city = 'Chicago'
   OR region_full = 'Chicago') AS full_match
from
  dv_location
where
(
  region ilike '%Chicago%'
 or
  postalcode ilike '%Chicago%'
 or
  city ilike '%Chicago%'
 or
  region_full ilike'%Chicago%'
)
 and metrocode is not null
 order by full_match desc;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set the order explicitly in the order by clause.

```
...
order by
case
  when city ilike 'Chicago' then 1
  when city ilike 'Chicago%' then 2
  when city ilike '%Chicago%' then 3
  else 4
end
```

or however you would like your results to be ordered ...